# Unable to view Wordpress site

Tags: wordpress

I had created a wordpress site close to 6 months back. Everything was fine till a few days back when we started to see the Wordpress "White Screen of Death" both at the front and back end.

After a lot of debug attempts, we decided to re-install wordpress and keep the old wp-content file.

Now this is visible on trying to access the site(wp_debug is set to false, so ideally it shouldn't be happening) -

1. Warning: require(/home/vaidya/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-error.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/vaidya/public_html/wp-settings.php on line 74

   2. Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/home/vaidya/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-error.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/vaidya/public_html/wp-settings.php on line 74

Line 74 on wp-settings -
require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-wp-error.php' );

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The error message says, the the file "class-wp-error.php" is missing.

It should be located in the folder "'/home/vaidya/public_html/wp-includes/". It seems that you did not copy all required files.